# Get running instances of devops pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to get all the running instances of a particular pipeline.

The API [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0),

[image]

This API allows us to get top 10K runs, but it does not seem to allow a filter where I can add a filter on the state of the pipeline, i.e. inProgress/running etc.

One way obviously is getting these top 10K runs and filtering them, which would be highly inefficient.

Is there a different API where I can get active runs of a pipeline or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this API: [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1). You can use `statusFilter` here:

[image]

Comment: the link seems to take me to the same API as in question. Could you please check if the link is correct? Thanks!

Comment: @OptimusPrime the link is updated.

Comment: yep working now, Will check and see if this works for the use case. Thanks!!